# Regex not working in C# (but works in other environments)

Tags: c#, regex

I simply want to remove newline between `[` and everything which looks like HTML tag or, in reverse, tag and `]`.

Came up with that one regex `new Regex(@"(\[{1}[\s\S](<[^>]*>)|(<[^>]*>)[\s\S]\]{1})",  RegexOptions.Multiline)`

I suppose that it would work, because [here](https://regex101.com/r/zdFoQj/1/) it looks fine.

But when I tried it in C# ([you can test it here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5C%5B%7B1%7D%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D%28%3C%5B%5E%3E%5D*%3E%29%7C%28%3C%5B%5E%3E%5D*%3E%29%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D%7B1%7D%5C%5D%7B1%7D%29&i=%5B%0D%0A%3Cb%3Etest1%3C%2Fb%3E%0D%0A%5D%0D%0A%3Cb%3E%0D%0A%5B%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%5B%0D%0A%3Cul%3E%0D%0A%3Cb%3Etest2%3C%2Fb%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%5B%0D%0Atest3%0D%0A%5D&o=m)) - get nothing.

How to make it work? Whats wrong?

Comment: It does not work at regexstorm.net because it uses CRLF line break style. The first `[\s\S]` only match CR, not LF. Also, `{1}` and `RegexOptions.Multiline` are redundant and can be removed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew hmm, never knew that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify it using:

```
new Regex(@"(\[.{1,2}(<[^>]*>)|(<[^>]*>).{1,2}\])",  RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was looking for!